# Problemas get_userid() - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework, cms

Estou passando por um probleminha. Se alguém puder me auxiliar, quando coloco minhas informações e clico em 'Submit', dá o seguinte erro na minha aplicação:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method Auth::get_userid()
>
> Filename: controllers/Pages.php
>
> Line Number: 95

E o código do 'Pages.php' é:

```
<?php 

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->auth->check_permission();
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p><span class="label label-danger">', '</span></p>');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('post');
        $this->load->library('table');

        $layout_vars = array();
        $content_vars = array();

        // Template da tabela
        $this->table->set_template(array('table_open'  => '<table id="grid" class="table table-striped">')); 
        $this->table->set_heading('#', 'Título', 'Data', 'Status', 'Ações');
        $query = $this->post->get_by_field('page','1');

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $this->table->add_row(
                $row->id, 
                $row->title,
                mdate('%d/%m/%Y', strtotime($row->created)), 
                status_post($row->status),
                // Ícones de ações
                div(array('class'=>'btn-group btn-group-xs')).
                anchor('admin/pages/edit/'.$row->id, glyphicon('edit'), array('class' => 'btn btn-default')).
                '<button class="btn btn-default" onClick="return confirmar(\''.site_url('admin/pages/delete/' . $row->id).'\');">'.glyphicon('trash').'</button>' .
                div(null,true)
            );
        }

        $content_vars['listagem'] = $this->table->generate();
        $this->wpanel->load_view('pages/index', $content_vars);
    }

    public function add()
    {

        $layout_vars = array();
        $content_vars = array();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Título', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {

            $this->wpanel->load_view('pages/add', $content_vars);

        } else {

            $this->load->model('post');

            $dados_save = array();
            $dados_save['user_id'] = $this->auth->get_userid();
            $dados_save['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
            $dados_save['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
            $dados_save['link'] = strtolower(url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')))).'-'.time();
            $dados_save['content'] = $this->input->post('content');
            $dados_save['tags'] = $this->input->post('tags');
            $dados_save['status'] = $this->input->post('status');
            $dados_save['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $dados_save['updated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $dados_save['image'] = $this->post->upload_media('capas');
            // Identifica se é uma página ou uma postagem
            // 0=post, 1=Página
            $dados_save['page'] = '1';

            $new_post = $this->post->save($dados_save);

            if($new_post)
            {
                // Salva o relacionamento das categorias
                $this->load->model('post_categoria');

                foreach($this->input->post('category_id') as $cat_id){
                    $cat_save = array();
                    $cat_save['post_id'] = $new_post;
                    $cat_save['category_id'] = $cat_id;
                    $this->post_categoria->save($cat_save);
                }

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Página salva com sucesso.');
                redirect('admin/pages');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Erro ao salvar a página.');
                redirect('admin/pages');
            }

        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $layout_vars = array();
        $content_vars = array();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Título', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {

            if($id == null){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Página inexistente.');
                redirect('admin/pages');
            }

            $this->load->model('post');

            $content_vars['id'] = $id;
            $content_vars['row'] = $this->post->get_by_id($id)->row();
            $this->wpanel->load_view('pages/edit', $content_vars);

        } else {

            $this->load->model('post');

            $dados_save = array();
            $dados_save['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
            $dados_save['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
            $dados_save['link'] = strtolower(url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title'))));
            $dados_save['content'] = $this->input->post('content');
            $dados_save['tags'] = $this->input->post('tags');
            $dados_save['status'] = $this->input->post('status');
            $dados_save['updated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            // Identifica se é uma página ou uma postagem
            // 0=post, 1=Página
            $dados_save['page'] = '1';

            if($this->input->post('alterar_imagem')=='1')
            {
                $postagem = $this->post->get_by_id($id)->row();
                $this->post->remove_media('capas/' . $postagem->image);
                $dados_save['image'] = $this->post->upload_media('capas');
            }

            $upd_post = $this->post->update($id, $dados_save);

            if($upd_post)
            {
                // Salva o relacionamento das categorias.
                $this->load->model('post_categoria');
                // Apaga os relacionamentos anteriores.
                $this->post_categoria->delete_by_post($id);
                // Cadastra as alterações.
                foreach($this->input->post('category_id') as $cat_id){
                    $cat_save = array();
                    $cat_save['post_id'] = $id;
                    $cat_save['category_id'] = $cat_id;
                    $this->post_categoria->save($cat_save);
                }

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Página salva com sucesso.');
                redirect('admin/pages');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Erro ao salvar a página.');
                redirect('admin/pages');
            }

        }
    }

    public function delete($id = null)
    {

        if($id == null){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Página inexistente.');
            redirect('admin/pages');
        }

        $this->load->model('post');

        $postagem = $this->post->get_by_id($id)->row();
        $this->post->remove_media('capas/' . $postagem->image);

        if($this->post->delete($id)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Página excluída com sucesso.');
            redirect('admin/pages');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_sistema', 'Erro ao excluir a página.');
            redirect('admin/pages');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Isso parece simples: o controlador não está encontrando o método `get_userid()`. O que é `$this->auth->get_userid();`? Um model? Um helper? Um controller? Aparentemente vc não carregou esse método na instância que está executando.

Comment: Qual biblioteca de Auth esta sendo utilizada?